# Read H.265 and VP9 frame?

Tags: c++, opencv, h.264, webm, h.265

I'm trying to compare 3 videos that are encoded by H.264, H.265, and VP9. 
All of them are made by a same YUV video.

I want to use OpenCV's function to read each frame of the video and do some comparison:

```
VideoCapture vCap1, vCap2, vCap3;
vCap1.open("h264.mp4");
vCap2.open("h265.mp4");
vCap3.open("vp9.webm");
Mat frame1, frame2, frame3;

while (vCap1.read(frame1) && vCap2.read(frame2) && vCap3.read(frame3))
{
    //do something
}
```

The `vCap1` opened successfully, but `vCap2` and `vCap3` won't open.
Did I miss something to include to make it work?

Or OpenCV even not support the other 2 formats?

Comment: Have a look at http://answers.opencv.org/question/10741/videocapture-format-supported-by-opencv/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After using google :-) I found that
http://answers.opencv.org/question/10741/videocapture-format-supported-by-opencv/

Especially you have the needed codecs installed on your system. You can visit also 
http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php

for codecs.

The documentation from OpenCV is indeed not very helpful. :-)

What I would try if you are running under linux:

strace -xfo dump

and take a look in the system calls. Maybe you can find some hints of missing codec files, used configuration files and or other failed system function calls. If so, you have a startpoint.